# Chromecast API - callback delay issue in statusupdate

Tags: android, google-chrome, chromecast

I'm working on chromecast apps and I observed below issues while debugging the app.

If I schedule an event at specific time, the event is applied with some delay in chromecast and also it was notifying to statusupdate listener about 600 milliseconds late.

Let me explain with an example:

> 1.Suppose we have an event at ’00:21:33:400’ (hh:mm:ss:ms), when we trigger the event exactly at specific given time we observed that it
>   is applied late in Chromecast (approximately 600 milliseconds) that is
>   the reason we are triggering event signals 600 milliseconds before the
>   exact event time.
>
> 2.And also observed that sometimes chromecast device is notifying the media status updates very late (i.e.. not triggering the
>   ‘StatusUpdate’ callback) when event applied. Due to this app may not
>   schedule the successive event if chromecast is updated with the
>   streaming position which is greater than the next event start time.
>   That is if next event is there at ’00:21:34:100’ time and if
>   chromecast is notified with the streaming position ‘00:21:34:300’, in
>   this case app will ignore the event and schedule/find the next
>   successive event which is greater than the ‘00:21:34:300’ streaming
>   position.

I have tried alot to fix this issue, Can you please help me out of this.

Comment: For (1), what type of actions is supposed to happen after your event is triggered? You can add logging information to your receiver to time different actions to see where it is spending its time; since it is your receiver, we can't really see what is happening. As for (2), what kind of time resolution do you expect to get for your application?

Comment: Actually I'm using default receiver application to play the video (using CastMediaControlIntent.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID). For (1) My main intention is to apply mute/un-mute events at specific given time codes. Sender application will send mute/un-mute messages to chromecast device but they are applying very late. For (2) When any event (mute/un-mute) executed in chromecast device my sender app should be notified to StatusUpdateListener immediately where in which I'm scheduling the next event to be applied. But StatusUpdateListener is calling very late after the event executed.

Comment: You didn't mention what kind of resolution you are looking for; "immediately" doesn't make much sense here.

Comment: My sender application should be notified as soon as any mute/un-mute event is executed in 'default receiver' app running in chromecast. Actually I'm getting this delay only when sender app is in background whereas it is working fine in foreground, I tried to acquire WifiLock and WakeLock but still no use.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I resolved my issue.

I verified the above issue by debugging the logs in styled receiver and observed that there is no delay.

Rather in sender application I used different method to get the current media streaming position.

i.e. 'mRemoteMediaPlayer.getApproximateStreamPosition()' - It was giving me the exact streaming position both in foreground and background.

whereas previsously I used 'mediaStatus.getStreamPosition()' method but sometimes its giving me the inaccurate streaming position.